# Почему нельзя говорить «два мужчины»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, числительные, одушевленность

> Из нижеперечисленных правильным будет вариант:
>
> - Можно и так, и так
> - **Двое мужчин**
> - Два мужчины

[*(Источник)*](https://ustaliy.ru/snax_quiz/test-po-russkomu-yazyku/16/)

«Правильный» ответ выделен.

Почему правильным будет только вариант *двое мужчин*? Может быть, словосочетание *два мужчины* все-таки вполне хорошо звучит?

Comment: Была такая дискуссия в родственном форуме: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/10834/%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b6%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-or-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b6%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd/10835#10835

Comment: @Alex_ander да, мне она знакома, и я за ваш ответ проголосовал.

Comment: А в первом пункте разве нужна запятая? Или здесь "пунктуация оригинала сохранена"?

Comment: @grizzly в цитате всё авторское.

Answer (score 4):

Практическая стилистика рекомендует употребление **собирательных** числительных  с существительными мужского рода, имеющими **окончание -а**: двое мужчин, трое юношей. Видимо, из-за того, что склонение на -а - это склонение в основном слов женского рода, **собирательное числительное сразу укажет на мужской пол**. Объясняют и чисто звучанием, якобы неблагозвучно сочетание  "два мужчины". Но может быть, просто непривычно, а не неблагозвучно?

В некоторых случаях, наоборот, не используются собирательные числительные, так как они вносят сниженный оттенок значения, например: два профессора, три генерала (не «двое профессоров», «трое генералов»). В отдельных учебниках указывается, что собирательные числительные не рекомендуются в книжных стилях, поэтому они не сочетаются с книжными словами. Но мне кажется, это из области политкорректности: генералы и профессора - "штучный товар", уважаемые личности, о них не говорят как о совокупности, каждый важен сам по себе.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm

Предпочтительно употребление **собирательных числительных**:

2) с существительными мужского рода, имеющими окончание -а: ***двое мужчин, трое юношей.***

***Два мужчины*** звучат не очень хорошо, так как в единственном числе сущ. м.р. *мужчина* по грамматике не отличается от сущ. ж. рода *женщина*. Мы говорим ***две женщины, три женщины***,  и это привычное для слуха сочетания **для всех сущ. на А/Я**, большинство из которых относится к ж. роду.

Соответственно, сочетание ***два мужчины, три мужчины*** воспринимается негативно. Окончание Ы/И Р.п. в ед.ч **воспринимается как указание на ж. род** для сущ. м. рода, которые в большинстве случаев имеют окончание А/Я (два мальчика). В этом и заключается неблагозвучность.

Сравнить: ***пять женщин, пять мужчин.*** Нулевое окончание в форме мн. числа **уже не указывает на род**, поэтому эти сочетания разрешены правилами.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему два мужчины звучат плохо. «Не отличаются по грамматике» странная формулировка, в которую не получается вникнуть.

Comment: Как известно, к 1 скл. относится очень небольшое количество одуш. сущ. м.р (мужчина, юноша, вельможа и др.), да еще неод. сущ. с суфф. ИН (домина), а сущ. ж.р. составляют большинство. И это при том, что склоняются они совершенно одинаково, в то время как во всех других случаях  прослеживается связь рода и склонения. Вот это и можно назвать одинаковой грамматикой. С другой стороны,  сочетание "двое женщин" также не рекомендуется использовать. Поэтому получается пара:две женщины - двое мужчин.

Comment: Понял. А как это связано со звучанием?

Comment: Я это объяснила в ответе: если сущ. оканчивается на А/Я, то в большинстве случаев это сущ. ж.р., которые сочетаются с числительным две. Впрочем, три мужчины тоже плохо звучат, есть в этом сочетании нечто ЖЕНСТВЕННОЕ.

Comment: "В её жизни было _трое мужчин_" для меня звучит настолько странно, что хочется спросить: одновременно или поочерёдно, и что их объединяет, кроме "неё" (и уж не однократно ли это с ней было)? Собирательные числительные объединяют сущности в группу не только грамматически, но и по смыслу, поэтому для выбора и здесь важен контекст.

Comment: Этих трех мужчин в этом конкретном случае объединяет ее жизнь. Обратим внимание, что в косвенных  падежах делается переход к количественным числительным. Так что для сочетаемости слов важное значение имеет форма. Этот принцип прослеживается во многих правилах.

Comment: Также заметим, что свою собирательность собирательные существительные выражают не всегда, а только в парных вариантах: два мальчика и двое мальчиков. Для  сущ. только мн. числа собирательные числительные  используются чисто формально: двое ножниц. Во всех случаях, где они применяются в счетных оборотах,  рекомендуется в косвенных падежах переходить к количественным числительным. Наиболее ярко собирательное значение проявляется для субстантивированных числительных: трое, троих, троим. Только здесь на законных основаниях используются все падежные формы.